# Choosing Between @Autowired and Constructor Injection in Spring: Which is Best Practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, constructor, autowired

In my Spring project, I'm injecting dependencies into my services using both **@Autowired** and **constructor injection**. While both approaches work, I'm unsure which one is considered the best practice in terms of maintainability, testability, and overall code quality.

I've used `@Autowired` for some services and constructor injection for others, and I'm seeking guidance on when to use one over the other. Which approach should I prioritize in my Spring project, and what factors or scenarios favor one over the other?

Thank you for your help and guidance!